# Zooming 2 imageviews side by side while keeping proportions

Tags: android, kotlin, zooming

I am working on a book page spread that has to be zoomable on both pages. I have found this example on github: [TouchImageView sample](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) which works beautifully on a single ImageView.

It also has a mirroring example for two images side by side but that is not the effect I need. The two pages need to be zoomed as if it was a single page and not 2 separate images.

Actually, I already achieved this effect by combining the two bitmaps side by side into a single bitmap and then loading to an imageview. However, this approach is very inefficient and is causing an Out Of Memory error from handling so many bitmap arrays.

So, I'm hoping to work with ImageViews instead of Bitmaps. Can anyone suggest how I might be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to get zoom from first view and then set it on second view. That way they will be both zommed at same level giving illusion of on.
Also as an alternative rather than zooming on image view set zoom on parent and let images hold 50% weight in layout of parent. They will start behaving as one unit then also

Comment: Thanks! The second option worked. I zoomed on the Linearlayout instead of the ImageViews. I normally use ConstraintLayout for everything so I hardly even thought of using a Linearlayout.